# Using Tasks to Add Excel Data with Same ID to MS Project - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

In excel I have the ID' numbers in column "A" starting on the second row (first row=header). In column "T" I have a duration for that ID on the same row.

In MS Project I have an ID column and an empty duration column. I want to add the duration from excel to MS Project on the correct ID row.

I think I can do this by using tasks and a For..To loop. I will need to use the ID in excel to look up the task in MS Project then write the duration from excel in the appropriate task in MS Project. So far, with some help, the code I have is:

```
'Find duration and assign to ID in Excel
For i = 2 To lastRow
date1 = .Cells(i, 15)
date2 = .Cells(i, 16)
    If .Cells(i, 18).Value = "No" Then
    answer = DateDiff("n", date1, date2)
    .Cells(i, 20) = answer
    End If
durationID = .Cells(i,1).Value
Next i

'Open MS Project and add Duration column
set wb = ActiveWorkBook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Task_Table1")
Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
appProj.FileOpen "File1.mpp"
Set aProg = appProj.ActiveProject
appProj.Visible = True


lastTask = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
taskID = ActiveProject.Tasks.ID

'Load Durations into MS Project to appropriate ID task
lastTask = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
For i = 1 to lastTask
    If taskID = Application.Workbooks("File1").Sheets("Task_Table1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
    answer.Copy
    appProj.SelectCell.ActiveCell
    end if
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying the duration into the user-interface, assign the duration directly to the task object. Alternatively (based on the comment below), update the Actual Start and Actual Finish date. Code to do both is included, but it doesn't make sense to update the duration if you are going to also update Actual Start and Actual Finish.

```
'Open MS Project
Set appProj = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
appProj.FileOpen "File1.mpp"
Set aProg = appProj.ActiveProject
appProj.Visible = True

'Find duration and assign to task
Dim Duration As Long
Dim tsk as MSProject.Task
With ws
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        date1 = .Cells(i, 15)
        date2 = .Cells(i, 16)
        ' get a reference to the task object using the ID stored in Column A
        Set tsk = aProg.Tasks(.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        ' Update duration 
        If .Cells(i, 18).Value = "No" And IsDate(date1) And IsDate(date2) Then
            TotalMinutes = DateDiff("n", date1, date2)
            WorkingMinutes = appProj.DateDifference(date1, date2)
            .Cells(i, 20) = WorkingMinutes 
            tsk.Duration = WorkingMinutes
        End If
        ' update Actual Start and/or Actual Finish
        If IsDate(date1) Then
            tsk.ActualStart = date1
        End If
        If IsDate(date2) Then
            tsk.ActualFinish = date2
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Note that there are two calculations included for the duration. The VBA `DateDiff` function returns the total number of minutes between two dates, whereas the MS Project `DateDifference` function returns the number of working minutes between two dates. The latter is likely what you want to use. Otherwise a 1 day duration (1440 total minutes) will turn into a 3 day task (1440 = 3 days * 8 hours * 60 minutes/hour).

Comment: To make this whole process easier, the dates from excel are already in their own columns under "Actual Start" and "Actual Finish." Many of the actual start and end dates are "NA" will this make the DateDifference not work? If it will work would I be able to keep this same For To function and change the date variables to equal the cells in MS Project? for example:

    `date1 = .Cells(i, "Actual Start")`

Comment: Also where would the result be printed? Do I need to Make a column before hand?

Comment: Are you actually needing to update the Actual Start and Actual Finish dates rather than the duration? You can store the TotalMinutes or WorkingMinutes variables in Excel if you want; I'll update the code for that.

Comment: There is currently not an Actual Duration in minutes column and the Actual Duration Column in MS Project doesn't put out the right output. So originally I exported the data to excel and did the DateDiff calculation there then tried to output that back into MS Project using the ID because copy and pasting the column won't attach the Durations to the correct ID number.

Comment: If you are trying to status your schedule with actuals data from Excel, set the Actual Start, Actual Finish, and/or Percent Complete fields. It is uncommon to directly set the Actual Duration column.

Comment: is there a command in vba that allows me to use the ID in Excel to look up the task in project then a different command to write the duration to "Duration1" using the ID to identify the row and select the Duration 1 field? Or should this idea be scrapped all together?

Comment: Yes, the code gets a reference to the task object so that field values can be set (e.g. Duration, Duration1, Actual Start, Actual Finish, etc.). I updated the code to clarify the task object by using a MSProject.Task variable (tsk). FYI: it is not necessary to "select" the Duration1 field.  You should run this code and step through it so that you can see how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued help Rachel!